# Many-worlds: Where does the energy come from?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy-conservation, quantum-interpretations

With regard to the theory that each time a wave function collapses the universe [splits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-worlds_interpretation) so that each possible outcome really exists - where does all the energy required to create all the new universes come from?

Comment: The question you raise is a good one and is precisely the reason why the many world interpretation is flawed...

Comment: @Killercam — you might as well ask where all of the extra **matter** comes from, which would clearly demonstrate how the OP misunderstands the MWI. The whole point is that the different "worlds" partition the matter and energy of the "parent" worlds from which they spilt, because taken together, they are only terms in a superposition making up the universal wave function. A criticism of MWI must proceed on different grounds.

Comment: @Killercam, MWI is surely criticizable for a few things, like the dependence of branches on the level of coarse graining or the failure to produce the right event statistic from just counting events, but conservation laws are not an issue. The global evolution is unitary and all conservation laws are exact. The only possible criticism could be based on the fact that for one observer the branching may break conservation laws subjectively, but that effect has a vanishing expectation value.

Comment: Personally, I don't like the interpretation that the law conservation of energy is based on observations within each world and that all observations within each world are consistent with conservation of energy, therefore energy is conserved. This to my mind is weak. Clearly it is based upon conservation of energy in QM being formulated in terms of weighted averages or expectation values. Then by some very basic stance that the energy of the total wavefunction, or any subset of, involves summing over each world, weighted with its probability measure. Hence energy conservation is not violated...

Comment: I don't like this. Moreover, this theory requires a fully consistant model of quantum gravity to 'relitivise' this theory - we don't have this...

Comment: @A.O.Tell I also don't like your statment 'There is no energy requirred to do that' - there is energy require for the split in MWI, to create the new world the internal energy of that world is provided by the anticident's energy, weighted by the QM probability density ascociated with the production of the new world (which I don't like). In addition to the above, this theory also has the 'Occam's razor' argument against it, which I also feel is a reason for not taking this theory to seriously (yet!)...

Comment: The problem is that you consider branches as *worlds*, where in fact they are not worlds. This is a misunderstanding. What actually happens is that you must consider your own brain to be a quantum object. When measurement occurs it becomes entangled with the measured wavefunctions. So what you call different words are merely different states of your brain with distinct memories of the measurement outcome. If you have a problem with energy conservation here then you must also have a problem with conservation in quantum mechanics in general.

Comment: No, I don't belive I miss-understand the theory (although this is a possibility :]). What I belive you are saying (which I understand) is if we take two systems that are entangled, one of which is an observer. Then the act of the collapse of the wavefunction is to split the observer into a number of copies, each copy observing just one of the possible results of a measurement and unaware of the other results and all its observer- copies...

Comment: Fine. However, what make the world physically real in the theory is that interactions between systems and their environments, including communication between different observers in the same world, transmits the correlations that induce local splitting or decoherence into non- interfering branches of the universal wavefunction. Thus the entire world is split, quite rapidly, into a host of mutually unobservable but equally real worlds. All outcomes exist simultaneously but do not interfere further, each single prior world having split into mutually unobservable but equally real worlds.

Comment: No, what I am saying is that you start with an initial state $|\psi>\otimes|0>$, where $|0>$ is the observer remembering not having measured anything. Now you measure the state and what happens is the joint state is transformed to $\sum_k M_k |\psi> \otimes |k>$, where $M_k$ are measurement operators and $|k>$ is observer remembering outcome $k$. In general this is an entangled state. The Schmidt number of this state is your number of branches. Notice that for a different observer who does not know anything of this measurement there is still just one universe.

Comment: I have never come accross it expressed like this. Does anybody else have comments on this - to me it seems a type of many-minds interpretation you describe. Thanks for your post...

Comment: @Killercam, nobody argued that "energy conservation is based on observations ..." etc. The only argument for energy conservation is a strictly mathematical one, and that is that the global unitary evolution strictly preserves energy measured as <psi|H|psi>. So no, world splitting does not require energy. And you don't need quantum gravity for that argument either.

Comment: @Killercam This is actually one of the main arguments made in favour many worlds. The question for those not supporting it is usually "Why should observers not themselves be quantum?". The formulae I wrote are just the usual quantum decoherence, about which you can read more on wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_decoherence

Comment: @Killercam, like I said, MWI has issues, and it's not clear if they can be resolved. Specifically for the emergence of the Born rule I'm quite certain that there will be no solution without additional (and questionable) postulates. However, MWI is based on a great idea, which is why so many physicists are willing to accept the consequences, i.e. the many worlds. There used to be no realist alternatives to MWI, but this has changed. I describe such an alternative in my blog at http://aquantumoftheory.wordpress.com - without many worlds and with the correct resulting event statistic

Comment: Related question [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/268696/wouldnt-the-thermodynamic-cost-of-creating-alternate-universes-make-the-many-wo).

Answer (score 8):

There is no energy required to do that. Unitary evolution preserves energy precisely. The reason is the way energy is calculated in quantum theory, and if that is applied to MWI then each branch only contributes with its squared modulus branch amplitude to the total energy. This is the only consistent way to count energy in quantum theory.

Comment: Thank you for your response A.O.Tell - I am a layman and my question stems from what I have learned from "popular" science books and TV documentaries. Is there a way to explain "unitary evolution" in a way that I might understand ?

Comment: Unitary evolution of a QM system, is the evolution that is described by Schrodinger's equation. At the quantum scale, the state of a system is a superposition of probable states weighted by complex numbers that remain constant in time. If the system remained on the quantum level - were not measured in classical reality where only a single state can be 'real' - both states could be considered equally 'real' - their evolution in time on the quantum level is unitary - as a single entity...

Comment: @hereComesBrod, the many worlds interpretation is derived from taking the Schroedinger equation, which describes the evolution of quantum states, literally. Unitary evolution is a characterization for what the Schroedinger equation does to the quantum state: It preserves its L^2 norm, or the length of the state vector. This kind of evolution has certain mathematical consequences, among them strict conservation of energy in the global quantum state. Since that state contains all the "worlds" or branches, energy is globally conserved and world splitting surprisingly does not require energy.

Comment: @Killercam, it's not very sensible to speak of "probable states" in context of MWI. The relative states approach does not assign probabilities to the wavefunction in the first place, instead it is treated as a real object. The probability interpretation is then supposed to emerge from relative state entanglement between observer and observed object.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I belive I am now offically out-of-my-depth, but I have lernt some stuff so thanks for that. all the best...

Comment: I don't understand A.O. Tell's answer. My understanding is that there are two distinct processes in the evolution of systems under quantum mechanics. The $U$ (unitary evolution) process and the $R$ process (reduction or collapse of the wave function) to use Penrose's notation. But Tell seems to be claiming that $U$ applies at the 'branchings' in the MWI. Certainly these are points at which $R$ is acting. Perhaps you could address this by expanding on your answer? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @MarkWayne - The point of MWI is that the projective dynamic is regarded as non-fundamental and instead derived as subjective feature of a global unitary evolution that entangles the observer with the observed system in a way that correlates an observed property with the system state possessing that property. So in an MWI context the objective evolution is unitary, always.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I didn't follow. Is "the projective dynamic" equivalent to Penrose's $R$? Perhaps a reference would help.

Comment: I can only guess what "Penrose's $R$" is, as I'm not familiar with his notation. But from what you wrote it is quite certainly the projective evolution as stated in the measurement postulate. It seems you are not too familiar with standard quantum theory, and having read one of Penrose's books is probably not too helpful in this matter. Try if you can understand this: http://philsci-archive.pitt.edu/8888/1/Wallace_chapter_in_Oxford_Handbook.pdf

Comment: I hope someone will read this. If no new energy is required for the "splitting" in the many-world interpretation because unitary evolution preserves it (as @A.O.Tell says the state contains all the world of branches already) what happens then to all the energy when, after an observation, only a single state becomes real?

Comment: The primary confusion in this thread seems to be in thinking that many-world postulates a new discrete process that generates new worlds/structures instead of just being about unitary evolution of a single state vector.  Here are some links to further reading that folks may find useful:  https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9410006 http://frankwilczek.com/2013/multiverseEnergy01.pdf 
 http://blog.jessriedel.com/2015/08/23/how-to-think-about-quantum-mechanics-part-6-energy-conservation-and-wavefunction-branches/  https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.05041

Answer (score 4):

There is no need for extra energy. The energy of all-worlds-together is conserved, and the energy within each-world is conserved on-average (which is what energy-conservation *means* in quantum theory).

Consider a collection of identical quantum systems, where each can be in two states - we can mark the states as state $|1\rangle$ and state $|2\rangle$. Each state may have its own energy associated with it, $E_1$ and $E_2$.

As part of the way quantum mechanics is built up mathematically, this means that each system can also be in a "superposition" state, i.e. a weighted sum like $\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}} |1\rangle+\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}|2\rangle$. Let us consider the systems to initially all be in this state.

Now, some device comes along and measures the system's energy. What happens?

First, consider things from the standard, no-multiple-world, (Copenhagen) interpretation.  On this view the systems will "collapse" to state $|1\rangle$ with energy $E_1$ 1/3 of the time, and to state $|2\rangle$ with energy $E_2$ 2/3 of the time. So *on average* we will receive that this kind of system has energy $1/3 E_1 + 2/3 E_2$. And this is the same amount of energy the system "had" before we measured it (e.g. it would cost us this amount of energy to prepare these systems). So there is a "conservation of energy" in the sense that *on average* energy is conserved. This is how conservation of energy works in QM.

Now, let us consider the measurement from the many-worlds-interpretation. Consider a *single* system in the above superposition state. In this case you get that reality "splits" into infinitely many worlds, so that 1/3 of them include the system in state $|1\rangle$ with energy $E_1$ and 2/3 in state $|2\rangle$ and energy $E_2$. So if we repeat this experiment again and again (measuring the whole collection of systems we considered under Copenhagen), we will again receive that *on average* energy is conserved.

And as a bonus, if we consider the *whole* collection of worlds from the many-worlds-interpretation, then it has the same energy as that average.

So if you take just *one* system in a superposition, you will find that in each world it has a different energy (what scientists call "quantum fluctuations") but that **on average** the system has the same energy it initially had, and you will also find that the total collection of worlds is still in this superposition state (there is no collapse) and hence still has the same initial energy.