# Many-worlds interpretation (MWI) and conservation of energy

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy-conservation, quantum-interpretations

I am not an expert of [many-worlds interpretation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-worlds_interpretation) (MWI), and what I say may be stated incorrectly. In that case i welcome corrections.
If the MWI is true and it explains quantum theory and it splits for any possible outcome, is there a global amount of energy/mass that is conserved?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Many-worlds: Where does the energy come from?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/41588/)

Comment: You know, what I particularly dislike is when an answer gets closed as a duplicate, and the answer on the duplicate is some pseudoscience tosh non-answer: _"There is no energy required to do that"._ What utter twaddle. Utmost apologies, user. As per Killercam's comment on the alleged duplicate, the question you raise is a good one and is precisely the reason why the many world interpretation is flawed.

Comment: The MWI does not "explain" quantum theory. It does explain the measurement process wrong, though. You can toss it into the dustbin on science history. It's no wonder, by the way, that it's "inventor" never did anything important in physics other than being tied to this intellectual nonsense.

Answer (score -1):

Lets say you take the theoretical function multiverse and use eulrtivic manifold distribution of stellar parallax (EMDSP equations) to find the conserved mass/energy of the two variables (energy, mass/consequence of gravitational flux) then one should find a percentage of mass being quite content and conserved.

Comment: could you elborate please ? do you have some refs for *eulrvitic* and *EMDSP equations*. Just to understand the relation to MWI ... TY